# 2010 KIA Rio Engine stalls, then won't start

Tags: kia, rio

My car is having problems staying on. When driving at first it seems like after it heats up after like 10 minutes it will jerk for a second and then rpm will go to zero then once you go to stop at times the car will turn off and it won't crank back up for like 30 minutes. Now I am lucky to get it to start at all and when it does start the engine sounds rough and it's kind of making this clicking noise.I thought at first maybe it was the fuel pump but someone assured me that can't be it.  I have done did all my coils and spark plugs/wires. I am thinking about getting help and replacing my fuel pump, timing belt and 02 sensor because I really don't have the money to take it to a mechanic so trying to learn how to do the stuff myself and watch videos on it all. Is there any help anyone could give me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any warning lights on, like the CEL? Many auto part shops will do OBDII scans for free, so you can investigate warning lights without needing to go to a mechanic. Also, this problem sounds like it could be electrical. Testing battery and alternator voltage with a multimeter can help diagnose.

Comment: Yes my father used his scanner and the only thing that came up was something about lights, I can't remember exactly what it was at this time. I will have to try and get to auto part store to have them do a test with the scanner. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As Hari Ganti mentioned above, if money is tight and you can *safely* drive there, you can get your check engine codes read for free at just about any parts store. This is a great place to start (ask them to write the code numbers down for you too, so you can research them on your own).

Based on the information you provided I do not think it's a fuel pump or the O2 sensor.

When, the engine starts misbehaving does it physically look like it's jumping or shaking? If so, that may indicate it's a bad crankshaft position sensor. Based on your description, I think it could be the crank sensor. If that's the cause of your issues, any parts store should be able to diagnose the issue with an OBD scanner and get you the part. I would suggest you at least look into the crank sensor before you change out that fuel pump.

Comment: My father used his scanner and it pulled up something about lights and that was it. I will have to try and go to auto part store to get them to use their scanner to see what it shows. When the car is having problems after it heats up after 10 minutes it jumps it feels like then the rpm goes down to zero and won't work after that until the car cools down for a while. The engine lately sounds rough and shaking and has a clicking noise to it. I will look into the crankshaft sensor as well as the o2, fuel pump and timing belt. Thank you!

Comment: @Gary90 Don't waste money on the fuel pump timing belt etc... until you can prove it. Remember time is money. You say you don't have money to take it to a mechanic for a diagnosis but most would be able to figure it out in a few hours and it's better than throwing parts at the car. Also don't rely on codes only to diagnosis a problem, auto parts stores are there to sell you stuff not to diagnose your car. I'd say Jared T is on to a possible cause of the stall/no start and is the path forward that I'd recommend pursuing first.